# Custom Boolean editor template in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, boolean, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I have a requirement to create an editor template in ASP.NET for model of type `Boolean`. The template should consist of one button that will display either '=' or '!=' as it's value. E.g.,
[Boolean Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Ckg.png)

When the user clicks the button it should inverse the boolean and submit the form.

I initiate the template with this line,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Negate, "MyBooleanTemplate")
```

I have the custom editor template working if I use a TextBox as the input and type in False or True when the form submits the model is picking up the new value.

```
@model Boolean
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

However, when I am trying to implement the custom template the model never picks up the change in value.

```
@model Boolean
@{
    string propertyName = Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
    string id = Html.IdForModel();
    string displayValue = Model ? "!=" : "=";
    string currentValue = Model.ToString();
    string changeValue = (!Model).ToString();
}

<button type="button" id="@id" name="@propertyName" value="@currentValue" onclick="this.value = '@changeValue'; this.form.submit();" class="btn btn-sm">@displayValue</button>
```

Am I right in thinking I need to have an element with the id, name and value attributes populated for the model binding to work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by editing a hidden field.

The editor template,

```
@model Boolean
@{
    string id = Html.IdForModel();
    string displayValue = Model ? "!=" : "=";
    string currentValue = Model.ToString();
    string changeValue = (!Model).ToString();
}
<input asp-for="@Model" type="hidden" />
<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('@id').value = '@changeValue'">@displayValue</button>
```

And invoked with,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Negate, "BooleanNegate", new { @class = "btn btn-sm" })
```